# Drools 6.2 How to generate and deploy DRL file from my own rule editor

Tags: containers, drools, workbench, kie

As a proof of concept, I have used Drools workbench to create data objects and DRL files. I created the jar file and deployed to kie server (with container). All done through workbench UI. I used KIE REST services from my c# application to post the input object via XML (using batch-execution) to fire the rules and I got the response that I was looking for.

But in real scenario, we will have our own rule editor (for ease of use) to create rules based on attributes from existing objects. Once the rule is saved in our DB, our plan is to generate the DRL file along with data objects.

My question is how to take this DRL file and build it as jar file?

Kie container needs a jar file with data objects and DRL file. Has anyone else done something similar?

I am trying to find the best way to deploy my drools rules file. Other alternative could be to use IKVM to generate dlls from drools jar file and integrate drools in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up converting drools 6.2 to .net dll using IKVM. Here is the post that i created to show how to do it:

http://droolstonet.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-use-drools-62-in-net-using-ikvm.html

Answer (score 2):

I think this has been asked and answered before, but here it is once more, code to compile DRL into a KieBase or KieSession.

```
public KieBase build( String drlPath ) throws Exception {
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( drlPath );
    kfs.write( "src/main/resources/some.drl",
                kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis ) );
    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();
    Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
    if( results.hasMessages( Message.Level.ERROR ) ){
        System.out.println( results.getMessages() );
        throw new IllegalStateException( "### errors ###" );
    }
    KieContainer kieContainer =
        kieServices.newKieContainer( kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId() );

    KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase();
    return kieBase;
}
```

Comment: laune, Thank you for your reply! This is a good alternative to calling the KIE execution server and it solves my problem of keeping the DRL file independent and outside. But this takes away the ability of calling the engine remotely. I failed to mention in my original post that I am planning to call this from my .net web api. I am thinking of writing the above code in java and then converting it as .net dll to call it from my c# code. Do you suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: Compiling from a DRL to a serialized KieBase is just a transformation: you have one or more DRL files and you end up with the binary KieBase. That has nothing to do with remotely calling the engine which runs using this KieBase.

Comment: yes, i got that part. I am looking for a way to call drools engine remotely with full control over the .drl file. My DRL file will be created by my own rule editor and application is written in .net. I need the ability to either call the engine remotely or somehow write the code in .net. I was able to call the engine remotely by setting up kie execution server with a jar file containing the DRL file and data objects but there is no easy way to modify the DRL file afterwards. I am just looking for ideas and see if anyone has implemented some thing similar. Thanks

Comment: Hi Asif, I am looking for the same thing. Once the drl is deployed to Execution Server, I am looking for a way to change the drl alone later without much to do with workbench. And deploy the changed drl to execution server